# Problem related to cyclic modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $x,y$ be two generators of a cyclic module, $M=Rx=Ry$, then $ann(x)=ann(y)$.

I think that it has to be associated to the fact that if $I,J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$ such that exists a module isomorphism $\frac{R}{I}\cong\frac{R}{J}$ then $I=J$. But I am not sure of that, could you tell me if I am right and in that case how to apply that statement to what I want to prove?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to math.stackexchange!

Towards your main question: The assumption $x \in Ry = M$ should allow you to conclude $\mathrm{ann}(y) \subseteq \mathrm{ann}(x)$. Do you see where to go from there?

Comment: Thank you for your welcome. I am talking about isomorphism as modules not as rings.

Comment: Good point, I removed that example.  Nevertheless, my comment about the annihilators is still applicable, and probably the easiest way to get to the result you want.

Comment: I was focused on having to use the statement I mentioned, but perhaps as you say it is much easier, I will try it.

Comment: The statement you mentioned is equivalent to the statement about cyclic modules: every cyclic module $M = Rx$ is isomorphic to $R/\mathrm{ann}(x)$. To get an isomorphism, think first about the $R$-module map $R \to M$ that sends $1$ to $x$. What is the kernel? Is this surjective?

Comment: But, which isomorphism could we define between $\frac{R}{ann(x)}$ and $\frac{R}{ann(y)}$?

Comment: Well, if $Rx = M = Ry$, as you assume, then $x = ay$ for some $a \in R$. You should check that $R/ann(x) \cong Rx$, using the map I suggested (you just have to check definitions!). In case you're not sure exactly how to get a homomorphism $R \to Rx$ by just deciding where $1 \in R$ goes, I was describing the function $f: R \to Rx = \{rx \,:\, r \in R\}$ defined by $f(r) = rx$. If $f(1) = x = ay$, what could our isomorphism be?

Comment: Sorry, I have thought the following: As a consequence of the statement you mentioned, we have that $M\cong\frac{R}{ann(x)}$ and $M\cong\frac{R}{ann(y)}$ and as we has the hypothesis $M=Rx=Ry$, we can assure that $\frac{R}{ann(x)}\cong\frac{R}{ann(y)}$ and, finally, due to the statement I mentioned, it is possible to conclude that $ann(x)=ann(y)$ as I wanted. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how to use those statements together.